# Reciting a Posuk representing your name at end of Shemona Esrei - source?

Tags: sources-mekorot, names, shemoneh-esrei

Many [Sidurim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42759&st=&pgnum=148) mention in the name of the Shela that one should say a Posuk at the end of Shemona Esrei that begins and ends with the same letter as ones name. Does anyone know where in the Shela this can be found?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9977

Comment: That is the Kitsur Shelah; a Sabbatian work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Kaf HaChayim ([122:11](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41181&st=&pgnum=135)) quotes the Eliyah Rabbah and the Sidur Nehora for this custom in order not to "forget your name" on the day of judgment. He also quotes [*Kitzur* Shlah](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42571&pgnum=193) in this subject. He also quotes [Rashi Micha 6:9](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16192/showrashi/true) that someone should read a pasuk that begins and ends with the letters of his name every day.

I subsequently found a letter from the latest Lubavitcher Rebbe ([Igros Kodesh 404](http://www.chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/ig/2/404)) who writes that he didn't find this minhag in the Shlah *or* Kitzur Shlah. The words in Rashi are in parentheses and the Rebbe strongly questions whether they were written by Rashi.

Comment: Where is the Shela though?

Comment: More importantly, where is that Rashi??

Comment: @HachamGabriel It seems from his not quoting it that there is none (which is why I italicized "Kitzur" in "Kitzur Shlah" — the Artscroll sidur also only quotes it in the name of the Kitzur Shlah). DoubleAA, the Rashi is in Michah (the Kaf HaChayim gives the words of the pasuk but not the chapter and verse; I didn't recognize it, but you can search through Michah for it)

Comment: @ba [Micha 6:9](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16192/showrashi/true) but I have it in parenthesis so maybe it's not original in Rashi?

Comment: +1 especially for the letter from the Lubavitcher Rebbe...Matim lo...

Comment: Note that Kitsur Shelah is a Sabbatian work.