# Looking for Pasuk for my son's name

Tags: minhag, names, aleph-bet-letters

My son's name is Kolunimus. I can't find a pasuk that starts with Kuf and end with Samech. Please help.

Comment: I checked Ateret it doesnt seem there is such a passuk

Comment: Hi Yosef, welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please provide some background as to what kind of _pasuk_ you are looking for, and for what purpose. You will be more likely to solicit satisfying answers that way. It always helps to express the motivation for the question too. Also, you might be interested in the source cited [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9977/does-one-choose-one-or-two-pesukim-for-names/9982#comment14142_9982).

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29629/759

Comment: I have the same issue with my son. I wonder if we can use a pasuk with a phonetically similar letter? Like sin or saf.

Comment: According to this Wikipedia link, the name "Kolunimos" (קלונימוס) is the Greek derivation of the Hebrew  'Beautiful Name' (יפה שם or שם יפה). Since a name from the Hebrew indicates the inner essence of the person like is understood from when Adam HaRishon named all the creatures, it might be appropriate to consider a posuk with 'Yud', 'Mem' or 'Shin', 'Heh'.   https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/משפחת_קלונימוס

Comment: @YaacovDeane the Greek _kallos_ is understood to have broader meaning to include "Good" along with "Beauty". Kalonymous is a portmanteau (_Kallos_ _Nymous_ = Kalonymous) graecized version of the name _Shem-Tov_. As such, one possible option would be like you suggested, only with _Shim_ and _Beis_.

Comment: @ShmuelBrown I can't speak or understand Greek, so I will need to take your word for that. But considering that one of the ancestors of Yehudah HaChassid was a Rabbi Kalonymous who preserved a long family teaching concerning tzeruf and Shemot, it sounds like a valid possibility. It would be like the Ba'al Shem Tov, Rabbi Yisroel ben Eliezer. In that case, it would be the root of teshuva, 'Shin', 'Bet'.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_00720_all.html#HtmpReportNum0018_L99) is the list of all the pesukim available with the pointer to those pesukim beginning with ק unfortunately, it seems that there are none that end in samech. Many people use sin instead of samech when necessary. However, the pesukim listed all end with shin. There are pesukim that end with Saf, but I do not know if that would help. I see that one of the pesukim cited actually ends in ט so a "sound-alike" would seem to be OK.

[בראשית פרק-לב-יא]  קָטֹנְתִּי מִכֹּל הַחֲסָדִים וּמִכָּל הָאֱמֶת אֲשֶׁר עָשִׂיתָ אֶת עַבְדֶּךָ כִּי בְמַקְלִי עָבַרְתִּי אֶת הַיַּרְדֵּן הַזֶּה וְעַתָּה הָיִיתִי לִשְׁנֵי מַחֲנוֹת:

[שמות פרק-לה-ה]  קְחוּ מֵאִתְּכֶם תְּרוּמָה לַיהוָה כֹּל נְדִיב לִבּוֹ יְבִיאֶהָ אֵת תְּרוּמַת יְהוָה זָהָב וָכֶסֶף וּנְחֹשֶׁת:

[ויקרא פרק-ח-ב]  קַח אֶת אַהֲרֹן וְאֶת בָּנָיו אִתּוֹ וְאֵת הַבְּגָדִים וְאֵת שֶׁמֶן הַמִּשְׁחָה וְאֵת פַּר הַחַטָּאת וְאֵת שְׁנֵי הָאֵילִים וְאֵת סַל הַמַּצּוֹת:

Answer (score 1):

According to [this forum](http://www.prog.co.il/archive/index.php/t-123890.html), since there is not such a pasuk, people would usually treat the name as either Kalman or Kalmish. For the former, your options are pretty varied:

> Joshua 15:60 - קִרְיַת בַּעַל הִיא קִרְיַת יְעָרִים וְהָרַבָּה עָרִים
>   שְׁתַּיִם וְחַצְרֵיהֶן
>
> Isaiah 51:5 - קָרוֹב צִדְקִי יָצָא יִשְׁעִי וּזְרֹעַי עַמִּים
>   יִשְׁפֹּטוּ אֵלַי אִיִּים יְקַוּוּ וְאֶל זְרֹעִי יְיַחֵלוּן
>
> Isaiah 52:8 - קוֹל צֹפַיִךְ נָשְׂאוּ קוֹל יַחְדָּו יְרַנֵּנוּ כִּי
>   עַיִן בְּעַיִן יִרְאוּ בְּשׁוּב יְהוָה צִיּוֹן
>
> Jeremiah 6:23 - קֶשֶׁת וְכִידוֹן יַחֲזִיקוּ אַכְזָרִי הוּא וְלֹא
>   יְרַחֵמוּ קוֹלָם כַּיָּם יֶהֱמֶה וְעַל סוּסִים יִרְכָּבוּ עָרוּךְ
>   כְּאִישׁ לַמִּלְחָמָה עָלַיִךְ בַּת צִיּוֹן
>
> Ezekiel 7:25 - קְפָדָה בָא וּבִקְשׁוּ שָׁלוֹם וָאָיִן
>
> Hosea 11:2 - קָרְאוּ לָהֶם כֵּן הָלְכוּ מִפְּנֵיהֶם לַבְּעָלִים
>   יְזַבֵּחוּ וְלַפְּסִלִים יְקַטֵּרוּן
>
> Zekhariah 11:3 - קוֹל יִלְלַת הָרֹעִים כִּי שֻׁדְּדָה אַדַּרְתָּם קוֹל
>   שַׁאֲגַת כְּפִירִים כִּי שֻׁדַּד גְּאוֹן הַיַּרְדֵּן
>
> Psalms 29:5 - קוֹל יְהוָה שֹׁבֵר אֲרָזִים וַיְשַׁבֵּר יְהוָה אֶת
>   אַרְזֵי הַלְּבָנוֹן
>
> Psalms 142:2 - קוֹלִי אֶל יְהוָה אֶזְעָק קוֹלִי אֶל יְהוָה אֶתְחַנָּן

For the latter, your options are a little more limited:

> Leviticus 21:6 - קְדֹשִׁים יִהְיוּ לֵאלֹהֵיהֶם וְלֹא יְחַלְּלוּ שֵׁם
>   אֱלֹהֵיהֶם כִּי אֶת אִשֵּׁי יְהוָה לֶחֶם אֱלֹהֵיהֶם הֵם מַקְרִיבִם
>   וְהָיוּ קֹדֶשׁ
>
> Ezekiel 45:4 - קֹדֶשׁ מִן הָאָרֶץ הוּא לַכֹּהֲנִים מְשָׁרְתֵי
>   הַמִּקְדָּשׁ יִהְיֶה הַקְּרֵבִים לְשָׁרֵת אֶת יְהוָה וְהָיָה לָהֶם
>   מָקוֹם לְבָתִּים וּמִקְדָּשׁ לַמִּקְדָּשׁ
>
> Psalms 29:7 - קוֹל יְהוָה חֹצֵב לַהֲבוֹת אֵשׁ
>
> Psalms 29:8 - קוֹל יְהוָה יָחִיל מִדְבָּר יָחִיל יְהוָה מִדְבַּר
>   קָדֵשׁ

An alternative option (and the one that I would choose, were it for me) is to treat the initial *quf* as a hard *kaf* and go with Isaiah 28:20. I know it's not such a nice pasuk in terms of what it's saying, but the first word in the sentence is only כי, while the second starts with *quf*.

[With thanks to @sabbahillel, whose [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/79868/1659) provided a convenient link for finding these psukim.]

Answer (score 1):

1. I found a place in Mishlei (Proverbs) where if you say two short consecutive pesukim the first begins with ק and the last ends with ס, if that's acceptable to say two pesukium for one's name.
   Proverbs 16:10-11 קֶ֤סֶם ׀ עַֽל־שִׂפְתֵי־מֶ֑לֶךְ בְּ֝מִשְׁפָּ֗ט לֹ֣א יִמְעַל־פִּֽיו׃
   יאפֶּ֤לֶס ׀ וּמֹאזְנֵ֣י מִ֭שְׁפָּט לַיהֹוָ֑ה מַ֝עֲשֵׂ֗הוּ כׇּל־אַבְנֵי־כִֽיס׃

https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.16.10-11?lang=he

1.b) There is another place in Mishlei with 2 back to back verses that the first starts with Kaf and the second ends with Samech, but it seems less favorable as something to associate with one's name, though I don't know if that should be a concern.  It's Proverbs 10:10-11

1.c) If it's helpful to other people searching for pesukim for names that aren't found in the siddur, on this website you can search every pasuk in Tanach that begins and ends with the letters you select. In order to use it replace the א in the search bar with the first letter in the name, and replace the ת with the last letter, and then click on the חפש (search) button. If you need any more help with it, let me know. http://162.243.116.217/tnk/find.php?q=%5E%D7%90.*%D7%AA%24

2. As I understand it's also okay to use a pasuk that has the letters of your name as the roshei teivot (initial letters) or sofei teivot (final letters) of consecutive words.  A friend of mine, AvnerMil, wrote a program that lets you search Tanach for these options.  Unfortunately I don't see any results for קלונימוס , though that's understandable since it's a long sequence of letters.  For other people who can't find a pasuk for their name this website might help them though.  http://secretorah.com/

Answer (score 0):

the רדב"ז in מגן דוד אות ש writes that

> גם דע כי יש בש' סגולה שאין כמוה בכל האותיות כי היא תשמש ג"כ בשימוש הס' וכמוצאה ממש

loosely translated

> "also you should know that ש has a unique virtue in that it can be used in place of a ס"

based on this some say to say a פסוק that starts with a ק and ends with a ש like

Leviticus 21:6 - קְדֹשִׁים יִהְיוּ לֵאלֹהֵיהֶם וְלֹא יְחַלְּלוּ שֵׁם אֱלֹהֵיהֶם כִּי אֶת אִשֵּׁי יְהוָה לֶחֶם אֱלֹהֵיהֶם הֵם מַקְרִיבִם וְהָיוּ קֹדֶשׁ

Ezekiel 45:4 - קֹדֶשׁ מִן הָאָרֶץ הוּא לַכֹּהֲנִים מְשָׁרְתֵי הַמִּקְדָּשׁ יִהְיֶה הַקְּרֵבִים לְשָׁרֵת אֶת יְהוָה וְהָיָה לָהֶם מָקוֹם לְבָתִּים וּמִקְדָּשׁ לַמִּקְדָּשׁ

Psalms 29:7 - קוֹל יְהוָה חֹצֵב לַהֲבוֹת אֵשׁ

Psalms 29:8 - קוֹל יְהוָה יָחִיל מִדְבָּר יָחִיל יְהוָה מִדְבַּר קָדֵשׁ

as @shimon bM mentioned in his answer